# Anyone else with this place of articulation of their rhotic sound?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english, ipa, rhoticity

As my question implies, I have an unusual manner of articulation for my rhotic sound, and I wonder if anyone else shares it: my rhotic sound is formed by bringing my bottom lip up so that my top teeth rest against the inside and below my bottom lip. When I write broad transcriptions, I simply use /ɹ/ because I just don't know if there even exists an IPA symbol for it.

For context, I'm a speaker of British English from the Black Country/West Midlands/Staffordshire area.

Comment: With the existence of that question, my question is already answered as I now know there are others with the same sound, so no worries.